# Calling excute() more than once on named cursor in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

am writing a Python script that will copy files from one dir to another and copy that filename into a doc archive PostgreSQL table.  The error I receive is below:

Camt' call excute() on named cursors more than once

Below is my code:

```
        cursor = conn.cursor('cur', cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM doc_archive.table LIMIT 4821')
      row_count = 0
    for row in cursor:
        row_count += 1
        print "row: %s    %s\r" % (row_count, row),
        pathForListFiles = srcDir
    files = os.listdir(pathForListFiles)
    for file in files:
        print file
        try:
            # Perform an insert with the docid
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO doc_archive.field_photo_vw VALUES)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual code? You've got unmatched quotes in the second execute.

when iterating through results, I normally use

```
for var in range(int(cursor.rowcount)):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Without trouble.

```
for var in cursor:
```

Seems wrong to me.

```
results = cur.fetchall()
for var in enumerate(results):
```

Is basically the same thing there. But would allow you to close your cursor in case you have to do another execute while iterating the first set of results. Generally I just declare another cursor in those instances.

In either case, your current code doesn't seem to be fetching the results of the execute. Which is important if you need to process that data.

Comment: thanks for catching those errors.  I am using the cursor.executemany function along with the code above and that part seems to be working.